# Error deploying to glassfish4 (Exception during lifecycle processing : java.nio.BufferUnderflowException)

Tags: java, glassfish-4, java-ee-7

I am getting error Exception during lifecycle processing java.nio.BufferUnderflowException while deploying my ear project (JEE7, using Java 8).

I am using mysql (jar file is copied to domain1\lib folder) and jersey (copied all jars to the same folder). below is what i get in GF logs

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=192m; support was removed in 8.0
Launching GlassFish on Felix platform
Aug 02, 2015 3:05:00 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner createBundleProvisioner
INFO: Create bundle provisioner class = class com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner.
Aug 02, 2015 3:05:01 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner$DefaultCustomizer getLocations
WARNING: Skipping entry  because it is not an absolute URI.
Aug 02, 2015 3:05:01 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner$DefaultCustomizer getLocations
WARNING: Skipping entry  because it is not an absolute URI.
Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishRuntime@6c3c0025 in service registry.
Found populator: com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.GFDomainXml
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : rootFolder=C:\Program Files\glassfish-4.1\glassfish
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : templateDir=C:\Program Files\glassfish-4.1\glassfish\lib\templates
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : src=C:\Program Files\glassfish-4.1\glassfish\lib\templates\logging.properties
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : dest=C:\Users\Vilsad\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0.2\config\GF_4.1\domain1\config\logging.properties
Info:   Running GlassFish Version: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1  (build 13)
Info:   Server log file is using Formatter class: com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.ODLLogFormatter
Info:   Realm [admin-realm] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.
Info:   Realm [file] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.
Info:   Realm [certificate] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.certificate.CertificateRealm] successfully created.
Info:   Authorization Service has successfully initialized.
Info:   Registered org.glassfish.ha.store.adapter.cache.ShoalBackingStoreProxy for persistence-type = replicated in BackingStoreFactoryRegistry
Info:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 93ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8080]
Info:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 0ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8181]
Info:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 0ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:4848]
Info:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 0ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:3700]
Info:   GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1  (13) startup time : Felix (2,608ms), startup services(1,415ms), total(4,023ms)
Info:   JMXStartupService has started JMXConnector on JMXService URL service:jmx:rmi://Lenovo-PC:8686/jndi/rmi://Lenovo-PC:8686/jmxrmi
Info:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 16ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:7676]
Info:   HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.0.0.Final
Info:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 16ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8181]
Info:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 16ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8080]
Info:   Initiating Jersey application, version Jersey: 2.10.4 2014-08-08 15:09:00...
Info:   Listening to REST requests at context: /management/domain.
Info:   Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishImpl@ae372b9 as OSGi service registration: org.apache.felix.framework.ServiceRegistrationImpl@67403656.
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   Created HTTP listener http-listener-1 on host/port 0.0.0.0:8080
Info:   Created HTTP listener http-listener-2 on host/port 0.0.0.0:8181
Info:   Created HTTP listener admin-listener on host/port 0.0.0.0:4848
Info:   Created virtual server server
Info:   Created virtual server __asadmin
Info:   Setting JAAS app name glassfish-web
Info:   Virtual server server loaded default web module 
Info:   Java security manager is disabled.
Info:   Entering Security Startup Service.
Info:   Loading policy provider com.sun.enterprise.security.provider.PolicyWrapper.
Info:   Security Service(s) started successfully.
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Info:   Initializing Mojarra 2.2.7 ( 20140610-1547 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.7@13362) for context ''
Info:   Loading application [__admingui] at [/]
Info:   Loading application __admingui done in 5,895 ms
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Severe:   Unknow type constant pool 18 at position107
Severe:   Unknow type constant pool 0 at position108
Severe:   Unknow type constant pool 0 at position109
Severe:   Unknow type constant pool 97 at position111
Severe:   Exception while deploying the app [************]
Severe:   Exception during lifecycle processing
java.nio.BufferUnderflowException
    at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.get(HeapByteBuffer.java:151)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.annotation.introspection.ConstantPoolInfo.containsAnnotation(ConstantPoolInfo.java:86)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.annotation.introspection.ClassFile.containsAnnotation(ClassFile.java:133)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.annotation.introspection.ClassFile.containsAnnotation(ClassFile.java:87)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.util.AnnotationDetector.containsAnnotation(AnnotationDetector.java:157)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.util.AnnotationDetector.containsAnnotation(AnnotationDetector.java:146)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.util.AnnotationDetector.hasAnnotationInArchive(AnnotationDetector.java:137)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.ApplicationArchivist.getApplicationFromIntrospection(ApplicationArchivist.java:393)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.ApplicationArchivist.createApplication(ApplicationArchivist.java:264)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarHandler.getApplicationHolder(EarHandler.java:578)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarHandler.initCompositeMetaData(EarHandler.java:555)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.getSniffers(ApplicationLifecycle.java:655)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:358)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Severe:   Exception while deploying the app [************]
```

Please advise

Comment: Hard to tell exactly from the comment but constant pool errors suggest that either your war file or some of your class or jar files are corrupt. I suggest doing a clean and build to see if that fixes it. Failing that, try redownloading any jars or even try a fresh Glassfish install.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaEE + Glassfish - BufferUnderflowException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28301584/javaee-glassfish-bufferunderflowexception)