# Deploy failure with NetBeans Java EE app with arbitrary code changes

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, netbeans, glassfish, glassfish-4.1

I have been working on an app on Glassfish 4.1 for school and I have been encountering a bug which is causing my app to fail to deploy. It seems like changing arbitrary things in the code, such as adding a decorator or even just adding an innocuous System.out.println statement, will cause the deploy to fail with an error in Glassfish's log.

Here is an example of the log:

```
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Severe:   Unknow type constant pool 18 at position21
Severe:   Unknow type constant pool 0 at position22
Severe:   Unknow type constant pool 0 at position23
Severe:   Unknow type constant pool 0 at position24
Severe:   Unknow type constant pool -47 at position25
Severe:   Unknow type constant pool 18 at position27
Severe:   Unknow type constant pool 0 at position28
Severe:   Unknow type constant pool 17 at position31
Severe:   Exception while deploying the app [APPOCase2]
Severe:   Exception during lifecycle processing
java.nio.BufferUnderflowException
    at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.get(HeapByteBuffer.java:151)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.annotation.introspection.ConstantPoolInfo.containsAnnotation(ConstantPoolInfo.java:86)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.annotation.introspection.ClassFile.containsAnnotation(ClassFile.java:133)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.annotation.introspection.ClassFile.containsAnnotation(ClassFile.java:87)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.util.AnnotationDetector.containsAnnotation(AnnotationDetector.java:157)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.util.AnnotationDetector.containsAnnotation(AnnotationDetector.java:146)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.util.AnnotationDetector.hasAnnotationInArchive(AnnotationDetector.java:137)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.ApplicationArchivist.getApplicationFromIntrospection(ApplicationArchivist.java:393)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.ApplicationArchivist.createApplication(ApplicationArchivist.java:264)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarHandler.getApplicationHolder(EarHandler.java:578)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarHandler.initCompositeMetaData(EarHandler.java:555)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.getSniffers(ApplicationLifecycle.java:655)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:358)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.ReDeployCommand.execute(ReDeployCommand.java:131)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Severe:   Exception while deploying the app [APPOCase2]
```

Comment: Have you looked at SO questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28301584/javaee-glassfish-bufferunderflowexception and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30360588/glassfish-error-exception-during-lifecycle-processing-java-nio-bufferunderflowex

Comment: Yes, but they don't seem to know exactly what the fix is. Just arbitrarily change things until it deploys.

Comment: If anyone finds this question in the future, no, I never solved this problem. Sorry.